# What is the image length/width in pixels of a native/unedited iPhone 6S / 6S Plus photo?

Tags: ios, iphone, camera

The iPhone 6S and 6S Plus have brand new ~12MP cameras. I'm trying to balance photo image quality in an iOS app with the processing power of the new devices, and as such, I need to know what the maximum image size (h/w) is in pixels.

What is the image size in pixels of a photo taken with either of these devices?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a general iPhone question. Try asking at http://apple.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @rmaddy nope, directly related to programming - since this is about managing photo image quality in an iOS app.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From my iPhone 6s Plus, the resolution of photo taken from the back camera is `4032x3024`, and from front camera is `2576x1932`.

Comment: Don't encourage off-topic questions by posting answers.

Comment: @rmaddy enforcing questions to be posted on their appropriate stack exchange site is one thing, giving help is another thing. There's no contradiction. Let's be nice to people asking for help, and make the world a little bit better. The question can be migrated or deleted later on if it doesn't belong here.